# Как правильней сделать запрос удаления по значению из массива?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql

```
echo "<table class='ram'><td>фио преп<td>должность
        <td>степень<td>контакт<td><input type='submit' name="."delteacher" . "value='Удалить выбранное'>";
    $t=("SELECT * FROM `преподаватели`");
$q=mysql_query($t)or die(mysql_error());  
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

        do
        {
        echo  "<tr><td>".$r['фио преподавателя']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$r['должность' ]."</td>";
        echo  "<td>".$r['степень']."</td>";
        echo  "<td>".$r['контакт преподавателя']."</td>".
        "<td><input type='submit' name='delteacher' value='Удалить выбранное'>";
if(isset($_POST['delteacher'])or die(mysql_error()) )
{       $del=("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`=`$r`" );
                $qu_del=mysql_query($del)or die(mysql_error());  }
        }
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q));echo "</table>"   ;
```

не знаю синтаксиса а может вообще ничего не знаю
направьте на путь истинный пожалуйста

Comment: Я правильно понял, что необходимо удалять того преподавателя, который выбран пользователем?

Тогда вы не понимаете того, как вообще работает PHP.

1) Должна быть HTML страница, которая отображает информацию (преподавателей) и выполняет определенные запросы к серверу.
2) Должен быть PHP код, который по запросу к нему выполняет определенные действия (удаление преподавателя). 

Можно, конечно, объединять вывод и действия в один файл, но точно не так как у вас...

Сначала одно действие (например, удаление преподавателя если надо), затем другое (получение преподавателей и вывод их списка).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте:

```
$del=("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`='".$r['фио преподавателя']."'");
```